# Showing Z has infinitely many subgroups isomorphic to Z

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I tried to do this as

Z has elements from -$\infty$ to $\infty$.

Let's take n number of elements out to $Z$.

Suppose n= 5
And the elements are 1,2,3,4,5.

Which forms a $S_5$ or a permutation group a of 5 elements .
A\c to Cayley Theorem 
"Every group is isomorphic to permutation groups " 
Thus $S_5$ is isomorphic to $Z$.

As n can have value 1 to $\infty$

And thus there are infinite number of  permutations groups from $S_1$ to $S_{\infty}$ and all are isomorphic to $Z$.

All comprising subgroups of $Z$.
Thus  Z has infinitely many subgroups isomorphic to Z .
Is this proof okay or needs some modifications ?

Comment: No, no, and no. - I assume that your $Z$ is the infinite cyclic group? Then it does not have any soubgroup isomorphic to $S_5$ .Also $S_n$ and $S_m$ are not isomorphic for $n\ne m$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No sir ,every subgroup is isomorphic to Z not $S_5$

Comment: @AbhishekRawat And how do you propose to make a group of order $5!$ have infinitely many elements?

Comment: If you need a subgroup to be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, doesn’t it need to be the same cardinality?

Comment: I don't think I found a single correct idea in the attempted answer... oh, yes, "$\mathbb Z$ has elements from $-\infty$ to $\infty$" is correct, sort of.

Comment: @rschwieb Sir I am saying all subgroups ate isomorphic to Z not $S_5$

Comment: @AbhishekRawat Your solution contains the phrase "Thus $S_5$ is isomorphic to $Z$." verbatim, which is what we are talking about.

Comment: @rschwieb  $S_5$ has some of the subgroups of Z okay... $S_5$ is a permutation group . by Cayley's theorem it will b isomorphic to Z . similarly thing holds for $S_n$. There are infinite n in Z so infinite $S_n$ comprising Subgroups of Z are isomorphic to Z

Comment: @AbhishekRawat Cayley's theorem says no such thing. $S_5$ does not "have some subgroups of Z". The elements of $S_5$ all have finite order and the nonzero elements of Z all have infinite order.

Comment: @rschwieb Sir contemporary algebra by Joseph a gallian  page 131 Cayley's theorem 1854

Comment: @AbhishekRawat you are making *big* mistake. Here the group is $\mathbb Z$, not a five element set. Unless you can prove a five element subset of $\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup (and hence a group), you can't use Cayley's Theorem the way you are using. Anyway, any subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ must be of same cardinality as $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Krish Oh sorry sir . Thanks for correcting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some facts and hints, assuming that $Z=\mathbb Z$ is the integers.

1. $\mathbb Z$ does not have any finite non-trivial subgroups.
2. In particular, $S_5$ is not a subgroup of the integers.
3. The groups you are looking for are infinite and free, just like $\mathbb Z$ and unlike $S_5$.
4. Consider the even numbers $2\mathbb Z$ -- what can you say about them?

Comment: You have gave *almost* every possible hints. I think it's worth pointing out that $\mathbb Z$ is cyclic and every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. (Just to complete the list.)

Comment: Thanks sir for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $n\Bbb{Z} = \{nm : m \in \Bbb Z\}$.